# How do Monitored Training Sessions work?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to understand the difference between using `tf.Session` and `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`, and where I might prefer one over the other. It seems that when I use the latter, I can avoid many "chores" such as initializing variables, starting queue runners, or setting up file writers for summary operations. On the other hand, with a monitored training session, I cannot specify the computation graph I want to use explicitly. All of this seems rather mysterious to me. Is there some underlying philosophy behind how these classes were created that I'm not understanding?

Comment: I think that the answer by Nicolas should pretty much cover you - no ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I can't give some insights on how these classes were created, but here are a few things which I think are relevants on how you could use them.

The `tf.Session` is a low level object in the python TensorFlow API while,
as you said, the `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` comes with a lot of  handy features, especially useful in most of the common cases.

Before describing some of the benefits of `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`, let me answer the question about the graph used by the session. You can specify the `tf.Graph` used by the `MonitoredTrainingSession` by using a context manager `with your_graph.as_default()`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf

def example():
    g1 = tf.Graph()
    with g1.as_default():
        # Define operations and tensors in `g`.
        c1 = tf.constant(42)
        assert c1.graph is g1

    g2 = tf.Graph()
    with g2.as_default():
        # Define operations and tensors in `g`.
        c2 = tf.constant(3.14)
        assert c2.graph is g2

    # MonitoredTrainingSession example
    with g1.as_default():
        with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession() as sess:
            print(c1.eval(session=sess))
            # Next line raises
            # ValueError: Cannot use the given session to evaluate tensor:
            # the tensor's graph is different from the session's graph.
            try:
                print(c2.eval(session=sess))
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)

    # Session example
    with tf.Session(graph=g2) as sess:
        print(c2.eval(session=sess))
        # Next line raises
        # ValueError: Cannot use the given session to evaluate tensor:
        # the tensor's graph is different from the session's graph.
        try:
            print(c1.eval(session=sess))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    example()
```

So, as you said, the benefits of using `MonitoredTrainingSession` are that, this object takes care of

- initialising variables,
- starting queue runner as well as
- setting up the file writers,

but it has also the benefit of making your code easy to distribute as it also works differently depending if you specified the running process as a master or not.

For example you could run something like:

```
def run_my_model(train_op, session_args):
    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(**session_args) as sess:
        sess.run(train_op)
```

that you would call in a non-distributed way:

```
run_my_model(train_op, {})`
```

or in a distributed way (see the [distributed doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) for more information on the inputs):

```
run_my_model(train_op, {"master": server.target,
                        "is_chief": (FLAGS.task_index == 0)})
```

On the other hand, the benefit of using the raw `tf.Session` object is that, you don't have the extra benefits of `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`, which can be useful if you don't plan to use them or if you want to get more control (for example on how the queues are started).

*EDIT (as per comment):*
For the op initialisation, you would have to do something like (cf. [official doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started):

```
# Define your graph and your ops
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_p)
    sess.run(your_graph_ops,...)
```

For the QueueRunner, I would refer you to the [official doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues) where you will find more complete examples.

EDIT2:

The main concept to understand to get a sense on how `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` works is the `_WrappedSession` class:

> This wrapper is used as a base class for various session wrappers
>     that provide additional functionality such as monitoring, coordination,
>     and recovery.

The `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` works (as of [version 1.1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8ddd727a4a43c0fba11550f3abc277a6e8d9f8c0/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py)) this way:

- It first checks if it is a chief or a worker (cf. the [distributed doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) for lexical question).
- It begins the hooks which have been provided (for example, `StopAtStepHook` would just retrieve the `global_step` tensor at this stage.
- It creates a session which is a `Chief` (or `Worker` session) wrapped into a `_HookedSession` wrapped into a `_CoordinatedSession` wrapped into a `_RecoverableSession`.
  The `Chief`/`Worker` sessions are in charge of running initialising ops provided by the `Scaffold`.

  > ```
  >   scaffold: A `Scaffold` used for gathering or building supportive ops. If
  > not specified a default one is created. It's used to finalize the graph.
  > ```
- The `chief` session also takes care of all the checkpoint parts: e.g. restoring from checkpoints using the `Saver` from the `Scaffold`.
- The `_HookedSession` is basically there to decorate the `run` method: it calls the `_call_hook_before_run` and `after_run` methods when relevant.
- At creation the `_CoordinatedSession` builds a `Coordinator` which starts the queue runners and will be responsible of closing them.
- The `_RecoverableSession` will insures that there is retry in case of `tf.errors.AbortedError`.

In conclusion, the `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` avoids a lot of boiler plate code while being easily extendable with the hooks mechanism.

Comment: Thanks - could you give some (pseudo ?) code on how we could replace MonitoredTrainingSession code using a plain Session ? It's rather complicated - for instance apparently a MTS will finalize the (default/) graph: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8ddd727a4a43c0fba11550f3abc277a6e8d9f8c0/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py#L191

Comment: Thanks - `tf.initialize_all_variables()` is deprecated btw, they get deprecated really fast. What I was interested in is the "under the hood actions" - one should go through the code as in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8ddd727a4a43c0fba11550f3abc277a6e8d9f8c0/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py#L191 - here the graph (which graph...) is finalized for instance. So MTS does a lot - and as we discussed in my previous question this can lead to nasty surprises. It would be interesting to have a rundown of the series the operations are performed - can't upvote more however

Comment: I added some descriptions on how the MTS works internally, I hope it will be helpful.
(I also modified the initialiser to  `tf.global_variables_initializer()`. Thanks for having spotted it).

Comment: Excellent thanks, will go through - could you turn `as of version 1.1` to a link to the code ? Hit y while viewing the code on github and it will be turned into a link to the particular commit (very important otherwise links break)