# Deadlock in tensorflow's MonitoredTrainingSession and slice input producer

Tags: python, tensorflow, deadlock

The code below deadlocks:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def train():
    """Stripped down and modified from cifar10.cifar10_train.train"""
    global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step() # for StopAtStepHook
    images = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
    labels = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
    images, labels = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images, labels],
                                                   shuffle=False)
    # input_var = tf.Variable([0, 0, 0])
    # images = input_var.assign(images) # TODO placeholder would work ?
    # input_batch = tf.scatter_nd_update(images, [[1, 2]], [77])
    input_batch = tf.scatter_nd_update(tf.Variable(images), [[1, 2]], [77])
    tf_print = tf.Print(input_batch, [input_batch])
    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
            hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=3)]) as mon_sess:
        while not mon_sess.should_stop():
            mon_sess.run(tf_print)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train()
```

If however I comment out `input_batch = tf.scatter_nd_update(tf.Variable(images), [[1, 2]], [77])` and uncomment the commented lines the program keeps printing:

> I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\kernels\logging_ops.cc:79] [1 2 3]

- why does it deadlock ? is it the right way to get around that using an extra variable as I do ? Or should I use a placeholder somehow ?
- what am I missing and it does not terminate after 3 steps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'm not sure about your first question but I believe what happens is that when you create the MonitoredTrainingSession it tries to initialise the variables of your graph. But in your case, one of the variable initial value relies on a dequeue operation hidden behind `tf.train.slice_input_producer`. As the queue has not started, the code deadlocks waiting for the queue to be enqueued.
   In your commented implementation, the `init_op` does run and so the queue can start and makes you code work fine.
2. Here is an explanation for your second question. 
   The `StopAtStepHook` relies on the `global_step` tensor being updated which is not the case in your script. This piece of code
   `tf_print = tf.group(tf.Print(input_batch, [input_batch]), tf.assign_add(global_step,1))` will work: basically it will group the `tf.Print` operation and the `global_step` incrementation together so each time you run `tf_print`, the `global_step` will be incremented.

   ```
   import tensorflow as tf

   def train():
       """Stripped down and modified from cifar10.cifar10_train.train"""
       global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step() # for StopAtStepHook
       images = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
       labels = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
       images, labels = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images, labels], shuffle=False)
       input_var = tf.Variable([0, 0, 0])
       images = input_var.assign(images) # TODO placeholder would work ?
       input_batch = tf.scatter_nd_update(images, [[1, 2]], [77])
       tf_print = tf.group(tf.Print(input_batch, [input_batch]),
                           tf.assign_add(global_step, 1))
       with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
               hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=3)]) as mon_sess:
           while not mon_sess.should_stop():
               mon_sess.run(tf_print)

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       train()
   ```

Comment: Makes sense thanks ! Isn't there another way ? Should I use a placeholder somehow ? (hadn't investigated the global_step API, hoped it magically updated in StopAtStepHook)

Comment: A `placeholder` won't work as the `scatter_nd_update` documentation is quite specific: `ref: A mutable `Tensor`. A mutable Tensor. Should be from a Variable node.` And this is confirmed by the error message : `TypeError: Input 'ref' of 'ScatterNdUpdate' Op requires l-value input`.

Also, you always have the ability to not use a local variable, e.g.:
`input_batch = tf.scatter_nd_update(tf.Variable([0, 0 ,0]).assign(images), [[1, 2]], [77])` if you prefer not to.

Comment: Oh thanks - I meant a placeholder instead of assignment, I am basically looking for the one right way. Welcome to SO :)

Comment: Btw there is an open question on MonitoredTrainingSession here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43245231/281545. A rundown or better equivalent code using a plain Session I think would be fairly useful

Comment: Thx a lot. I just posted an answer, I hope it will be helpful!